# How to use CDI / weld without javax.el and javax.servlet.jsp in classpath

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld, weld

Is is possible to use weld (CDI) without `java.el` or `javax.servlet.jsp` present?

Those 2 packages are awfully heavyweight for deployment, and are not terrible useful on some environments (such as Android).

It seems that the `org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize()` does some lookups for both of those.

At least, is is possible to have the apis for el and jsp present, but without an implementation (ie, a null implementation)?

Or stated another way, is el and jsp a requirement for CDI to exist?

And yes, it is possible to have a non-CDI servlet environment without `javax.el` and `javax.servlet.jsp` present.

Comment: These packages are `provided` by all web containers, so you should not add it to your own application as libraries. If you are doing maven builds, make sure to have them as provided.

Comment: Jetty has el and jsp as optional (a good thing).  They are not provided by a classloader, or required to even run Jetty if you choose to not use them.  Anyway, the question isn't about container, but rather the CDI spec first, and the Weld implementation requirements second.

Comment: Evaluating a potential patch to make those optional in the `WeldServletLifecycle` (just like the `javax.enterprise` classes now)

Comment: Thanks for info, I was not aware of that feature in Jetty.